# Tensorflow not detecting the GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I know this has been posted multiple times but none that I came across worked.
The environment is Pycharm Education license, python version 3.11. The libraries I installed were numpy 1.26.2, pandas 2.1.4, scikit-learn 1.3.2 and tensorflow 2.15.0. They also installed their dependancies of course. The device has a Intel i5 10300H CPU and a Nvidia GTX 1650 GPU.

When running

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices())
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU"))
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices("CPU"))
```

in the aformentioned environment I get this output:

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]
[]
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]
```

Which to my knowledge shows that tensorflow doesn't detect or recognize my GPU.

I have updated the graphics drivers through GeForce Experience, installed Cuda Toolkit, but don't know what to do with it exactly, reinstalled tensorflow as some suggested. Command nvidia-smi displays the GPU. There are many old answers saying to install tensorflow-gpu but it seems to be included in the tensorflow package now. Don't really know what else I could try.

Comment: Did you install `cudnn`?

Comment: No, downloading it now.

Comment: @TimRoberts Wait, just to clarify, do you mean the python package nvidia-cudnn-cu12 or the library from developer.nvidia.com or possibly something else I didn't mention?

Comment: Have you checked this: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native_1

Comment: I suspect you'll need both.

Comment: @Frightera Following the link you posted worked. The problem seems to be that tensorflow after 2.10.X doesn't work natively on windows, only on WSL.  Don't know if I'm supposed to self answer the question and mark it as complete, as I've seen on some other questions?